# Set text from alert dialog

Tags: java, android

Heres my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            alert.setTitle("What's Your name?");
            alert.setMessage("Seems like you're new here! What's your name?");

            // Set an EditText view to get user input 
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            alert.setView(input);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

              }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // Canceled.
              }
            });
```

This opens a Edit text with a ok and cancel button

How do i do this when you hit ok it will change the TextView's text to what ever is inside the box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                 String newText = input.getText().toString();
                 textView.setText(newText);
            }
});
```

Comment: If you could accept the answer, its more of a confirmation than a upvote.